# rvest trouble: cannot capture the data in the table

Tags: html, r, xml, rvest

I am trying to get some specific data in a web database result;

[image: This is the page view by chrome browser]

I am interested in "NPI type" data in this page. This is  "Organization" in this page (otherwise it is "Individual). Although it is shown as a small picture in the web page, the html of this part is coded as ;

```
img src="/static/registry/img/glyphicons-90-building.png" alt="Organization" title="Organization
```

I want to get "Organization" text in this page by the rvest. My code is

```
webadr<-"https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/registry/search-results-table?number=1104090158"

data1<-read_html(webadr)

st<-data1 %>% html_nodes("img") %>% html_text()
```

and "st" should be the object "Organization". But the reulst is jut " " " ".

Answer (score 0):

You need to hit the attribute, not the node text:

```
library(rvest)

webadr <- "https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/registry/search-results-table?number=1104090158"

data1 <- read_html(webadr)

data1 %>%
  html_nodes("td > img") %>%
  html_attr("alt")
## [1] "Organization"
```